# facing some cakephp sorting issue

Tags: sorting, cakephp

use one column `'plan_start_date'` in listing..

use two database table(`'plan','plan_renewal'`) for fetching data in `'plan_start_date'` column..

if start date found in 'plan_renewal' table, then show start date from 'plan_renewal', otherwise show start date from 'plan' table..

when sorting these data 'desc/asc' facing some issues..
it only sort data (start date) according to plan table only..

```
how can sort date according both table's data(in acs or desc order) ??
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using? Could you update your question with some of the code you have tried so far that isn't working.

Comment: using cakephp 2.x version..

Comment: Please post your relationships between models. A sample of the expected output would also be helpful.